# Remove Promoted Links Overlay Color

Tags: promoted-links

Is there a way to remove the overlay color?  Thanks in advance! [image]

Answer (score 1):

I know it is too late for your answer but still i found the solution.

There is default `corev15.css` with class `.ms-tileview-tile-detailsBox` in which background-color is specified which is defined for Promoted Links.

You can change the `background-color:transparent` in CEWP.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible ingresando este codigo en un editor de scripts(It is possible by entering this code in a script editor)

```
<style>
  .ms-tileview-tile-detailsBox{
        background-color: transparent;
}
</style>
```